# Android Studio ignore --core-library flag

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project, which i want to configure on my computer.

On anothe computer it works, but with old version of Android Studio 0.4.0 whenever I use 0.5.2

The proble is that after I launch app it show error

> Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'coreLibrary()'!
>           Possible causes could be:
>           - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent 
>           - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method
>           - or there is a mistake in a build script

But in order to make it work I have to use this flag! I already tried to enable it in the settings>Android compilers > "Add --core-library" flag,  but it useless...

in the gradle i have next part of code:

```
    dexOptions {
    coreLibrary true;
}
```

This error showed only after activation this lines... Without them it don't work...

HOW SHOULD I FIX THIS? Maybe it is because of different versions.. if yes then how should I write to make it work?

After changing to coreLibrary = true It compilate Gradle fine BUt stille require after Run --core-library flag using.... But i already set it to true in settings...

It shows not almost the same error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':BusKg:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    D:\Programms\Programms\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4\dx.bat --dex --output D:\Android2\BUS.kg\marshrutka\BusKg\build\pre-dexed\debug\annotations-api-6.0.26-27e56569b50edbdd453f9bc0e568cde1fbfa621b.jar C:\Users\Viacheslav\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat\annotations-api\6.0.26\50aeafa144ed17913ed44d18ac61afd505a9e3e\annotations-api-6.0.26.jar
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    trouble processing "javax/xml/ws/WebServiceRef.class":
    Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
    when not building a core library.
    This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
    in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
    Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
    core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
    going on.
    However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
    namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
    from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
    assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
    compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
    It is also often of questionable legality.
    If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
    appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
    distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
    the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
    If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
    building an application, then be forewarned that your application
    will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
    prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
    application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
    system. You will be to blame for this problem.
    If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
    core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
    repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
    your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
    conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
    you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
    that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
    lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
    1 error; aborting
```

Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? This error message seems pretty dire.

Comment: Well... i want to at least to launch the project and after that try to fix this... But unfortunately i don't even know how to enable this core-library

Comment: If you don't already deeply understand what's going on and KNOW that you need this flag for a very specific reason, then you probably don't need it. In particular, WebServiceRef is an annotation for J2EE web services, which pretty much have no place in an Android app. I think what you're trying to do probably doesn't make any sense in Android.

Answer (score 14):

```
project.tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex) {
    additionalParameters=['--core-library']
}
```

does not work proper,and get the error:

**Could not get unknown property 'com' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.**

I solve the problem by adding this to android block.

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    additionalParameters=['--core-library']
}
```

Hoping this is helpful to you!

Comment: dexOptions with just additionalParameters worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio 1.1.0, navigate to :

File --> Other Settings --> Default Settings --> Compilers --> Android Compilers

You will find the check-box to Add "--core-library" flag, but this does not seem to be working.

Instead editing the file app/build.gradle

Disabling pre-dexing inside `android {}` using

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

and modifying `Dex task` using

```
project.tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex) {
    additionalParameters=['--core-library']
}
```

solves the problem.

*Edit:* Full contents of app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appId"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    project.tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex) {
        additionalParameters=['--core-library']
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        // more exclude files here if conflicts
    }
}
```

Comment: can you just show working `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: The change is not in AndroidManifest.xml but in app/build.gradle. Updating the answer with the contents of the file.

Answer (score 2):

I think we cannot enable `--core-library` via `dexOptions`.

We know that `dexOptions` delegated to a [com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/2116d9ced9083ba62bfe0b8caefbb4d58fe06e24/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/dsl/DexOptions.groovy) object, which implements [com.android.builder.core.DexOptions](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.android.tools.build/builder/0.12.1/com/android/builder/core/DexOptions.java).

From the source code, we know it doesn't support `--core-library`.

From [Issue 79280: dexOptions in gradle plugin don't support coreLibrary](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79280)

> You can do it manually by
>
> - disable pre-dexing (this is because our cache would have issues if we allow adding extra params)
> - modify the Dex tasks to add --core-library as an extra parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have the same problem and I resolved it by checked the box "Add --core-library" in /Preferences/Compiler/Android Compilers

Comment: Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Unknown command-line option '--core-library'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem! Unfortunately I solved it only by installing version Android Studio 0.4.2.... Other methods didn't help... Probably, later, it is better to configure project for new version of Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to exclude libraries which are causing this issue. For Example: -

```
compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.+'){
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
```