# Dependencies for using Apache POI to read excel files in Android

Tags: java, android, excel, apache

I want to use Apache POI to read and write excel files (both xlsx and xls) in Android. But I cannot resolve dependency issues that I currently have.

If I have only these two dependencies in my gradle file

```
compile files('libs/poi-3.12-20150511.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.12-20150511.jar')
```

Then I get the following error:

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
            at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.<clinit>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:59)
            at com.gargzdai.spreadsheet.MainActivity.readData(MainActivity.java:131)
            at com.gargzdai.spreadsheet.MainActivity.prepareForReadingData(MainActivity.java:109)
            at com.gargzdai.spreadsheet.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
```

This is the code I'm using to read excel files:

```
    if (isXlsxFile)
        myWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(file));
    else
        myWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileStream);
    Sheet mySheet = myWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator rowIterator = mySheet.rowIterator();
```

It seems that I should add xmlbeans library. After I add this dependency to my gradle file:

```
compile files('libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar')
```

After I add this dependency I get the following error during gradle build:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Any ideas on how should I approach this problem?

Comment: One thing to look at is that Java 8 isn't supported by Android yet: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development

Comment: Thanks for noticing this but it didn't change anything.

Comment: is there different version of poi dependency for android ? i just want to know.I am using  <!--EXCEL SHEET START -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>  
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>3.9</version>
  </dependency> for java projects and it works

Comment: Yes, there is. The newest version in 3.12 and you can get it from here:
https://poi.apache.org/download.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem. org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml is referencing at the end stax:stax-api, which contains core packages javax.xml.*. The compiler (or predexer or however it is called in android studio) aborts the compiling with a long warning. There are three ways to solve this:

1. Use another library than poi, [if there is any that also supports xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267025/read-xlsx-file-in-java)
2. Recompile the dependencies. I started recompiling the stax-api. You need to change the package name of the classes wit a tool like jarjar, which is also mentioned in the error output of android studio. The problem: you will also have to recompile the xmlbeans library that references and uses the stax-api. At this point I gave up.
3. Set the --core-library switch during compilation. This is not recommended as one can see in androids error message. Nevertheless, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163341/android-studio-ignore-core-library-flag) is a discussion on how this would work. Doing this, you should also recompile stax-api and drop all classes that are defined in android.jar (javax.xml.XMLConstants, javax.xml.namespace.*)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me: `dependencies {
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.12'
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.12'
implementation 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.0.0'}`

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two dependencies in your build.gradle module file

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'
implementation 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember to sync the gradle file after saving it. That solved the issue for me. The sync button appeared at the top of the gradle file after a change was made.

[image]